# Openjdk 11 on busybox crash on SIGSEGV in libc.so

Tags: java, docker, glibc, busybox

I'm trying to create docker image based on busybox with openjdk 11, for minimal java image

I used `progrium/busybox` as base image which contains glibc and installed zlib.so which was missing: `opkg-install zlib-dev`
Then I downloaded from https://jdk.java.net/11/ the compiled linux jdk.

Then when trying to run `java -version` it outputs the version but then crash.
This is from the created log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6d7013d5c0, pid=47, tid=62
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.2+9) (build 11.0.2+9)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.2+9, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x385c0]  __call_tls_dtors+0x10
#
```

full log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TEgNVRheDvphWxQFan_Frocc7Em8iQYI/view?usp=sharing)

I'd appreciate any advice or direction on how to solve this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have **two** versions of `libc` installed simultaneously in your base image - `GNU libc` and `musl libc`:

```
$ docker run -it progrium/busybox
/ #
/ # /lib64/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Buildroot) stable release version 2.18, by Roland McGrath et al.
<...>
/ # 
/ # /lib64/libc.so
musl libc (x86_64)
<...>
```

The `libc` package, provided by opkg, is `musl libc`, and all binaries from opkg packages are built against it. This includes `zlib`, so, it turns out that `musl libc` is a transitive dependency for Java binary.

However, Java binary itself in your case is built against `GNU libc`, so you end up with two `libc` versions being loaded at the same time:

```
/ # LD_DEBUG=libs /opt/jdk/jdk-11.0.2/bin/java
<...>
572: calling init: /lib64/libc.so
<...>
572: calling init: /lib/libc.so.6
```

The result is [pretty unpredictable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30154384/7191047), and in your case this is a segmentation fault.

If you want to download the JDK build from the official OpenJDK website, you have to use the Alpine Linux OpenJDK build, because Alpine also uses `musl libc`.

Unfortunately, this build is not present for OpenJDK 11, but you may check that [Early Access OpenJDK 13](https://jdk.java.net/13/) build for Alpine Linux works pretty well (but note that it is **not** a stable release build!).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I prefer currently JDK 11 because it is LTS. I tried `busybox:glibc` which compiled againt glibc but it is missing libz.so, and also `frolvlad/alpine-glibc` which contain glibc in seperate dir, but I couldn't manage to change the java shared libraries loading path

Comment: To be honest, I still use Java 8, which has Alpine version of OpenJDK image, `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine`, so I'm pretty surprised by the fact that there is _really no simple way_ to obtain a slim image of OpenJDK 11. Considering all the alternatives... If the stability really matters, I would not bother with lots of craftsmanship to save some megabytes and instead would use public Debian-based image. It is huge, but anyway it will be more stable than a custom hand-made slim build.